# Access ArcGIS Python environment, installed via in Anaconda Navigator, from .bat script in normal cmd window?

Tags: python, arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, bat

I'm trying to run a Python script (shapefile_upload.py) which uses ArcGIS libraries. I installed the ArcGIS libraries by following exactly [these instructions](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022005).

The Python script uploads a shapefile to ArcGIS Online. It takes several arguments (ArcGIS Online URL, path to shapefile, username, and password).

I need to run the Python script in a .bat file. The .bat file looks like this:

```
call "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ArcGIS_Test\python.exe" shapefile_upload.py URL Path_to_shapefile -U Username -P Password
```

When I select "Open Terminal" in Anaconda Navigator for the ArcGIS_Test environment and execute this .bat script, the shapefile is successfully uploaded to ArcGIS Online.

However, when I open a regular cmd window (not via Anaconda Navigator), and run the .bat script, I get an error that it's unable to ArcGIS Online, and the shapefile is not uploaded.

I think the Python environment is not used properly by the .bat file when run from the basic windows cmd window, even though I'm calling the Python interpreter within the correct environment.

What do I need to change in my .bat script for the environment to be set properly?

Comment: This question isn't really a GIS question at this point. It's a how do I activate and run a specific Conda environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## If you do not have ArcGIS Pro currently installed on your machine

If you installed the `arcgis` library through conda but **do not** have ArcGIS Pro installed on yout machine, you need to call the `activate.bat` file from the main conda folder and point it to your newly created environment.

Edit your `.bat` file to look like this:

```bsh
@echo on

set env_name=ArcGIS_Test
set conda_dir=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
set env_dir=%conda_dir%\envs\%env_name%

call %conda_dir%\Scripts\activate.bat %env_dir%

%env_dir%\python.exe shapefile_upload.py URL Path_to_shapefile -U Username -P Password

pause
```

## If you have ArcGIS Pro currently installed on your machine

According to [this ArcGIS documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/get-started/using-conda-with-arcgis-pro.htm), you need to refer to `propy.bat` instead of `python.exe`.

So have the contents of your `.bat` file to be as follows:

```bsh
set arcgis_dir=C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro
"%arcgis_dir%\bin\Python\scripts\propy.bat" shapefile_upload.py URL Path_to_shapefile -U Username -P Password
```

#### Small note

You might need to update the `env_name`, `conda_dir` and `arcgis_dir` variables to the actual paths and names used on your machine (i.e., the `set xyz=abc` statements at the top of the bash files).

Comment: Thanks. The propy.bat is only if you run the arcgis libraries from the ArcGIS Pro installation, which we don't have on this computer. You can also install the arcgis libraries through Anaconda Navigator (see link I included), and now I'm just trying to figure out how to run it using a .bat script.

Comment: Aaaahhh, okay! I'll edit my answer then, give me a quick moment.

Comment: There, I've edited the answer. It now addresses both cases (with and without ArcGIS Pro currently being installed).